# Switching multiple buttons visibility

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, visibility

In my application im trying to switch the visibility of two transparent buttons (i know this is rather hackish) within a RealViewSwitcher. I am changing the visibility based upon the current page of the RealViewSwitcher. I can get the first button to work, however the second never becomes active. Here is my code:

///////////////

```
    if(realViewSwitcher.getCurrentScreen() == 0)
    {

        final Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.test.com"));
                startActivity(intent);

                btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
    } 

    else if(realViewSwitcher.getCurrentScreen() == 2)
    {
        final Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setVisibility(0);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {       
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                String[] tos = { "info@email.com" }; 
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tos); 
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body"); 
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject"); 
                intent.setType("message/rfc882"); 
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Email Client");

            }
        });
    }

    ///////////////
    //end
    /////////////////////
```

And here is the xml

```
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: Don't hardcode int values for calls to things like setVisibility. Always use View.GONE etc.

Comment: Should else if(realViewSwitcher.getCurrentScreen() == 2) be else if(realViewSwitcher.getCurrentScreen() == 1) (change 2 to 1)? If you could post your complete layout XML that would be helpful.

Comment: It must be equal to 2, thus referring to the third page of the realViewSwitcher. Only the first and third pages have hyperlink activities on them. The second and fourth page are just text. My xml will be up in a moment, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just needs a little cleaning.

1. First of all, your buttons should be declared as fields. As it is, they are simply instance variables of the if statement.
2. The click listeners should be declared outside the if statement, for the same reason. Declare them in `onCreate()` or wherever suits your fancy.
3. Set up a switch for the `getCurrentWindow()`. It's easier to work with than an `if... else if... else if...`.

Might I suggest:

```
final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
final Button btn2 = (Button )findViewById(R.id.btn2);

//Inside onCreate() or similar
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.test.com"));

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  //Required to start a new activity
        startActivity(intent);

        btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
});

//In the same place
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        String[] tos = { "info@email.com" }; 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tos); 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body"); 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject"); 
        intent.setType("message/rfc882"); 
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Email");
        btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

//Later, in your other functional code
switch (realViewSwitcher.getCurrentScreen()) {
    case 0:
        //do your stuff
        break;
    case 2:
        //other stuff
        break;
    default: //If you need it
        throw new Exception("Oops...");
}
```